# How to use limitTo when displaying sections of data

Tags: angularjs

I am displaying items based on date, want to limit the number of items.

#### HTML

```
<div ng-repeat="itemDate in itemDates = (itemsList()  | unique:'Date' | orderBy:'sortingOrder') | limitTo:displayNum ">

    <div>{{itemDate.Date}}</div>   
    <div ng-repeat="item in itemsList()| orderBy:'sortingOrder' | orderBy: 'Time'">
        <div ng-show="itemDate.Date === item.Date">
            <div>{{item.name}},{{item.Date}}</div>
        </div>
    </div>         
    <div>
        <button ng-click="increaseBy(1)"> More </button>
    </div>     
</div>
```

#### Controller.js

```
$scope.displayNum = 1;
$scope.itemsList = function () {
    return itemService.getItemsList();
};
$scope.increaseBy = function(num) {
    $scope.displayNum += num;
};
```

#### Current Output:

```
Today
item1, date
More
Yesterday
item2,date
More
```

The more button is displaying in each section. I want to display button more at the end of the list like the following and it should hide when the all items are displayed.

```
Today
item1, date
Yesterday
item1, date
More
```

Comment: Can you give an output example, it is confused to understand what format you want to display the data. Or maybe you can edit the last paragraph?

Comment: currently it is displaying in 3 sections .first section is "Today". under "Today" it is displaying few items then "more" button. then second section "Tomorrow" under this displaying items,followed by a "more" button. but I want to display more button at the end, not in between sections.

Comment: Can you put the `div` with `button` out of the outer `div`?